# Return only array values which it's keys are in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which looks like:

```
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'city', 'birthday', 'money');

$values = array('id' => 10,    
    'name' => 'Jonnas',   
    'anotherField' => 'test',
    'field2' => 'aaa',
    'city' => 'Marau', 
    'field3' => 'bbb',
    'birthday' => '0000-00-00',
    'money' => 10.95
);
```

Is there a PHP built-in function which retrieves an array filled only with the keys specified on `$fields` array `(id, name, city, birthday, money)`?

The return I expect is this:

```
$values2 = array(
    'id' => 10,
    'name' => 'Jonnas',
    'city' => 'Marau',
    'birthday' => '0000-00-00',
    'money' => 10.95
);
```

P.S.: I'm looking for a built-in function only.

Comment: there is no built-in function like u looking for...u have to use both  loop and 'built-in function for key'.

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2755304/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4780861/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11265133/218196 ... full list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array_intersect_key+is%3Aanswer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$values2 = array_intersect_key($values, array_flip($fields));
```

If the keys must always be returned in the order of `$fields`, use a simple `foreach` loop instead:

```
$values2 = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $values2[$field] = $values[$field];
}
```

Comment: My real array has float values, so the array_flip function raises the following error: "Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!"

Comment: @fonini: In your example, the `$fields` array does not have float values.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry about that

Comment: @fonini: Well, provide a proper example. If `$fields` is really an array of keys, then how can the values (the fields/keys) be floats? As you already noticed, float values cannot be keys.

Comment: @fonini: This does not change anything for the `$fields` array. I think you applied `array_flip` to the wrong array. Given the example in your question, this answer will work just fine.

Comment: @FelixKling Man, you're right! I didn't drink enough coffee for today. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[array_intersect_key — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```
<?php
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'city', 'birthday');

$values = array('id' => 10,    
    'name' => 'Jonnas',   
    'anotherField' => 'test',
    'field2' => 'aaa',
    'city' => 'Marau', 
    'field3' => 'bbb',
    'birthday' => '0000-00-00'
);

var_dump(array_intersect_key($fields, array_flip($values)));
?>
```

Comment: I am little late to post the answer....

Comment: You still need to flip the fields ...

Comment: +1 for the quick correction ...